# Selenium context click on compound class

Tags: java, css, html, testing, selenium

I'm currently finding the element of the compound class `sfnDialOrChartPanel sfnEditBorder` by using `findElement(By.cssSelector(".sfnEditBorder"))`. It seems to find it ok but when it performs the context click no menu shows up which I expect to happen.

Am I using the `CSS` selector wrong somehow? Is there a way to show the selenium mouse location somehow so I can see exactly where it is right clicking?

Thanks

Chris

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver_);
WebElement masterPanel = webDriver_.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sfnEditBorder"));
actions.contextClick(masterPanel);
```

I tried to see if there was more than one `.sfnEditBorder` returned by doing this..

```
List<WebElement> masterPanel = webDriver_.findElements(By.className(".sfnEditBorder"));
```

However there is only one... any more ideas?

Comment: It's not your selector that is wrong, if I understand you correctly.  Is there an html element above or below it that you could try clicking on?  I have occasionally clicked on an inner element and had it work, where an outer element wouldn't.

Comment: I've tried elements above, not below as it's the last one, but none of them seem to work - hence wanting to be able see where the mouse is and work out what is going on!

Comment: 99% positive selenium isn't clicking in the wrong spot.  Have you tried Actions?  Or simulating a click with javascript?

Comment: I've added above the code I'm using. That is 100% the class of the thing it should be right clicking on.

Comment: I posted an answer before I saw your edit.  If you go to chrome console, how many elements do you see when you type `$('.sfnEditBorder')`?

Comment: You could easily verify to ensure that the locator is correct, by changing `.findElement` to `.findElements`. If the list that is returned from that has more than one element inside it, your locator may well be wrong. What browser is this in? What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Sorry I added the code of something I was trying out. Updated now.

Comment: Firefox. Selenium 2.33.0

Comment: One html class and then twice more in javascript

Comment: Please explain or provide a screenshot...I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: Ok so this is an HTML5 web application written in Java using Google Web Toolkit. I searched in the generated html in the chrome developer console for "sfnEditBorder". It came up three times, once in the class attribute for the element I'm trying to right click on, and twice more in some javascript.

Comment: I did what arran suggested and it seems the list size is zero.. `List<WebElement> masterPanel = webDriver_.findElements(By.className(".sfnEditBorder"));`

Comment: You are still doing `By.className()`  Change that to `By.cssSelector()`

Comment: Ergh. Clearly I need a break from this. "size=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't actually doing the right click. you have to call `actions.perform();`

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver_);
WebElement masterPanel = webDriver_.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sfnEditBorder"));
actions.contextClick(masterPanel);
actions.perform();
```